# How can I remove this error,* sqlite:///TMDB.db (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: genres.genre_id?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

[image: This is how the database looks]

Question 10

How many movies are in the database that are both a Romance and a Comedy?

Options:

373
484
262
595

This is my code:

```
SELECT movies.title
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN genremap ON movies.movie_id = genremap.movie_id

UNION

SELECT genres.genre_id
FROM genres
LEFT JOIN genres ON genremap.genre_id = genres.genre_id
WHERE genres.genre_name = "Comedy" OR genres.genre_name = "Romance" 
ORDER BY movies.title
LIMIT 50;
```

I also tried this but it returns an error:

```
SELECT m.title, g.genre_id, gs.genre_name
FROM genremap AS g
LEFT JOIN movies AS m ON m.movie_id = g.movie_id

UNION

SELECT gs.genre_id
FROM genres AS gs
LEFT JOIN genres ON g.genre_id = gs.genre_id
WHERE gs.genre_name = "Comedy" OR gs.genre_name = "Romance" 
ORDER BY movies.title
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find values for Comedy and Romance in `genres`, use them to count movies in `genremap`:

```
select count(1) from (
  select movie_id from genremap gm join genres g on g.genre_id = gm.genre_id 
  where genre_name in ('Comedy', 'Romance')
  group by movie_id having count(1) = 2)
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BrYnoxdq)

You can also join with movies if it is possible that `genremap` has orphaned rows.